# Docker RUN apt-get update returned a non-zero code:132

Tags: docker, apt-get, ppc64le

Below is `docker build -t test:test .` log

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.225MB
Step 1/3 : FROM ppc64le/ubuntu:jammy
 ---> b4cdd8bc1823
Step 2/3 : ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0d6079ed0b29
Step 3/3 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in fca7ae125244
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 132
```

It is clear to me that apt-get update is causing a problem but I don't know how to solve it. I googled everywhere but doesn't seem that peopple are getting this error code. Is it something related with ppc64le related? Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

Per man bash:

"When a command terminates on a fatal signal N, bash uses the value of 128+N as the exit status"

So a 132 code indicates signal 4. which per `kill -l`

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP   2) SIGINT   3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL   5) SIGTRAP
```

is SIGILL, illegal instruction. So either you aren't running on a POWER9+ ppc64le machine, or your qemu setup isn't emulating it.

Power8 machines can fail on SIGILL as apt-get can get compiled with POWER9 instructions (as I found out in [docker library issue #12726](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/12726)).
Note 22.04 jammy is POWER 9/10+ per [release](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/release/), and [build](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041740.html).